# Confusion with 'confusion matrix' in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, confusion-matrix

I am running SVM classifier on LingSpam dataset and I have got following confusion matrix in WEKA:

[image]

If we consider legitimate->positive class and spam->negative class, then True Positives=2405 and True Negatives=470.

But I'm confused about False Negatives and False Positives. If you read the 'Table of Confusion' section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix), it seems False Positives=11 and False Negatives=7. But if you read [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-weka2/index.html?ca) (please use Ctrl+F and search for 'What do all these numbers mean?'), it seems False Positives=7 and False Negatives=11.

I'm confused :(. Please help me out! Moreover, what is IR_Precision and IR_Recall in WEKA? Is it legitimate_precision and legitimate_recall OR spam_precision and spam_recall?

Note: Considering legitimate emails as POSITIVE class and spam as NEGATIVE class.

Comment: This might be better at http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you define as the "positive" class. There is nothing special about "legitimate" that means it is the positive class; you could do it either way.

It would be more conventional to call "spam" the positive class here, since it is the unusual attribute you are detecting. In that interpretation, there are 470 true positives, etc. In your interpretation there are 2405. Neither is wrong per se, but again, it's probably more customary to treat "spam" as the positive class.

Same answer regarding precision and recall. It is for the positive class, but depends on what you have used as the positive class. If you fed in this confusion matrix, it would be looking for precision and recall of "legitimate" as the positive class. I would reverse that, ideally.

Comment: Thanks Sean! So the IR_Precision and IR_Recall reported by Weka are the precision and recall of legitimate class. But you haven't told me about FP and FN. What are FP and FN in this matrix? There are two links in the question and if you will read it, there are two different possibilities for FP and FN.

Comment: FP and FN are the top-right and bottom-left entries in the confusion matrix. It is not ambiguous *once* you define what "positive" is! There is no inherently positive class. What if you were classifying dogs vs cats -- which is positive? the answer is whichever one you picked to be positive. Here you chose "legitimate" to be positive. That's fine but not conventional. But it is in no way ambiguous given that choice.

Comment: In the first link, Cat is being taken as positive class and other animals or dog as negative class. FP is bottom-left and FN is top-right entry there! (opp to what u have told!) Whereas, in link 2, FP and FN are the top-right and bottom-left entries respectively (as you told), a being positive class and b being negative class. This is what my real confusion is!

Comment: Moreover, after viewing results from Weka Experimenter, it shows value of top-left as FN and value of bottom-right as FP! I'm really confused now! Further, I have read somewhere while googling that the results given by Weka about TP, FP, etc in confusion matrix are somewhat obscure.. please guide me

Comment: Not sure about that, but in what you posted in your question, the "true" cells are definitely top left and bottom right. Because that's where predicted = actual.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, if you take a careful look at the research articles on spam classification problems, almost all of them have defined spams as positives and hams as negatives. In your case, it is the opposite. So, it has a chance to confuse the readers.

However, the Weka confusion matrix is perfectly okay. Here are the definitions of the positives and negatives according to classic spam classification tasks:

```
True positives: original label spam, predicted label spam (very good)
False positives: original label ham, predicted label spam (very dangerous)
False negatives: original label spam, predicted label ham (less dangerous)
True negatives: original label hams, predicted labels ham (very good)
```

In your case (if you want to compare with what has been said in classic spam classification tasks),

```
True positives: 470
False positives: 7
False negatives: 11
True negatives: 2405
```

Just make the confusion matrix upside down to read them this way. I think the main confusion comes from your definition of positive and negative.

Hope that helps.